# ScrollView or ListView for many different items?

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I am looking for what is the best practice for my case. I need to add dynamic content to a view, these elements are very deferent between them so this made me think what is better? For now I am using ListView but I had problems with the recycled view especially because I need to take some value for each row given by the user. In the rows there may be edittext, checkboxes, buttons, etc.

What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with both approaches.
RecyclerView is now the preferred one because it is the new API to achieve this goal. It is more powerful, more flexible

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many items you have.

For a relatively small number of distinct item types, a `ScrollView` will do just fine.

However, if you have a large number of items (even if they are distinct layout types), you might want to consider a `RecyclerView` so that the framework only needs to measure the `View`s that are visible on screen. A `ScrollView` will measure all of its children regardless of whether they are on screen or not, so if you have a lot of items you may incur a significant performance hit.